# How to handle push notification from the Geoloqi API

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So the geoloqi api uses this to handle push notifications.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
   [LQSession handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

The userInfo only contains aps and a geoloqi key that has a token. How do I turn that token into information about the place/trigger?